# Class inheritance, and requiring subclasses from different files with Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

I am trying to organize my code a bit but having issues with undefined superclasses. I'm hoping it's just a load path problem, but I can't figure it out. I am running this with:

```
coffee rooms.coffee
```

**rooms.coffee**

```
Room = require('./rooms/room')

module.exports = class Rooms extends Object
    constructor: ->
        @
```

**rooms/room.coffee**

```
module.exports = class Room
    @Active: require('./active')

    constructor: (@id) ->
        @users = {}
```

**rooms/active.coffee**

```
Room = require('./room')

console.log Room #=> {}

module.exports = class Active extends Room
    constructor: (@id) ->
        @type = "Active"
        super
```

And if I try to do `new Active`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
```

`Active`'s `super` is listed as `undefined`:

```
[Function: Active] __super__: undefined
```

Why `Room` undefined? (or rather, just an empty Object?)

**Update**

This was caused by a circular dependency as many people below pointed out. I ended up just putting the subclass definitions right inside of the baseclass definition, rather than try to keep them in separate files. Something like this:

```
class Room
  constructor: ->
    # ...

  class @Active extends Room
    constructor: ->
      # ...

  class @Inactive extends Room
    constructor: ->
      # ...

active   = new Room.Active
inactive = new Room.Inactive
```

Comment: Off-topic, but what does `#=>` do?

Comment: It's just a comment, I am showing the output of that command (it outputs just an empty object)

Comment: I see. Thought I'd missed some fancy new syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where simplifying the code down to its most primitive parts (while still seeing errors) is illuminating. If we remove the requires and strip out most of the code, we can get a structure like this:

```
class Room
  @foo = "bar"

class Active extends Room

console.log Room.foo
```

which prints: `bar` as expected.

So now lets try getting a little closer to the original example:

```
class Room
  @foo = Active

class Active extends Room

console.log Room.foo
```

This prints `undefined` because `Active` was not defined when Room.foo was defined.

Finally, let's look at the case were the definitions are reversed:

```
class Active extends Room

class Room
  @foo = Active

console.log Room.foo
```

This throws an error because it isn't possible to extend `undefined`.

The last two cases represent changing the require order in your original example. Having the definition of a base class depend on its subclass should cause your OOP alarm bells to start ringing! :)

There may be a way to change the definitions slightly to make this work, but code with these kinds of mutual dependencies tends to be unmaintainable at best. I'd recommend figuring out a way to completely decouple the classes.

Comment: You're right, it was a circular dependency problem. I ended up just placing the subclass definitions inside of the `Room` class, rather then trying to keep them in separate files. See my update. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about this but I may have had a similar problem - it might be to do with the fact that the file *room/active.coffee* is before *room/room.coffee* alphabetically, so when *active.coffee* file is loaded the **`Active`** class is first looked at, *room.coffee* and **`Room`** haven't been yet, so the superclass can't be found.

I got around this by using the `-j` operator at compile time, so while your *.coffee* files are nice and organised, they compile into a single *.js* file, which has other advantages as well.

Answer (score 0):

`@Active: require('./active')` remove this, or move this somewhere else. You have a circular dependency. When you define `room.coffee`, you're telling it to require `active.coffee` before it can finish defining `Room`, and `active.coffee` requires `Room`, so `Room` will be `undefined` when `active.coffee` is required.

You should be able to just add a `Room::Active = require('./active')` at the end, but then I ask why you even need this in the first place o.O